# What is the difference between a single-stage pump and a centrifugal pump?

Tags: motors, pumps

[Here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/dc-brushless-centrifugal-circulation-small-water_1764477502.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_title.10875798tE00rA) is the small $12 \; V$ pump that I am looking at. The manufacturer called the product as *DC brushless *centrifugal* circulation small water pump* but under its description it mentions that it is a *single stage pump*.

[image]

> I wonder what the difference is? Is it a misleading description or title or do those terms are used interchangeably?

Comment: No, it's not misleading, and they are not interchangeable. You can have two stage centrifugal pumps, and single stage non-centrifugal pumps. The number of stages is its own independent property.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Hi Jonathan, thanks for commenting. So it is not a centrifugal pump? The title says it is? I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single stage and centrifugal are describing two different properties.

A single stage pump is a pump that only has one acting impeller stage doing work on the fluid. If you put two pumps in series, you could say that you have a two-stage pumping setup. Some pumps are built with multiple stages - this is usually for high pressure applications.

A centrifugal pump is the style of impeller / casing. Centrifugal pumps use an impeller similar to what is shown below, and they rotate in a way that utilizes [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) to do work on the fluid, in this case creating pressure and driving the flow.

[image]

You could have a single stage centrifugal pump, a multiple stage centrifugal pump, a single stage NON-centrifugal pump, or a multistage NON-centrifugal pump setup. Below is a generic example of a multiple stage centrifugal pump - note that there are multiple impellers, and they don't have to be completely separate pumps - each of these increases the pressure supplied to the next impeller, so as to increase the pressure of the next impeller's discharge.

[image]

For the vast majority of applications (especially water), single stage centrifugal pumps sized correctly cover most applications.